# Plotting Vectors with Sympy

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, math, sympy

Is it possible to plot a vector created with the new sympy.vector?

```
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D

# Create the coordinate system
C = CoordSys3D('C')
v1 = 2*C.i + 3*C.j
```

Answer (score 2):

The Sympy Plotting Backend module exposes the [`plot_vector` function](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/vectors.html#spb.vectors.plot_vector). In this documentation page you'll find a few example about its usage.

Refer to [this page for installation](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

Comment: This is useful - but I wish to plot a single vector, not a field!

Answer (score 0):

After plotting something (or even nothing) using spb, you can use matplotlib function as follows:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *
# SymPy Plotting Backends (SPB)
from spb import *

p=plot(xlim = (-4, 4), ylim = (-4, 4), 
       aspect = "equal", size = (5, 5), show=False)
ax=p.ax
ax.quiver(0, 0, 2, 3, 
          angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
```